# How to get block proposer address systematically using web3 library?

Tags: eth-2.0, validators

With Ethereum 2.0, the blocks are proposed by a random validators. My question is, how to get addresses of block proposers systematically (web3.py or web3.js)? For example: proposer of block `#15665199` is `0xab2e2aa2c1f599699ad427067be262f2672f52ea8b66dd99bb5732a98029424d1f0272f96acda05059134de72bbe1670`. The information is taken from [here](https://beaconscan.com/slot/4828898).